# Как вывести координаты точки в двухмерном массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, координаты

Как мне вывести координаты точки из 2d массива? Нужно вывести координаты всех точек, где находится число `5`. Числа генерируются случайным образом с помощью [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()). Вот код:

```java
int[][] array = new int[3][4];

for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[index].length; j++) {
        array[index][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }
}

for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        System.out.print(array[row][column] + " | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

достаточно просто, вывод всего массива у вас уже реализован, достаточно добавить условие фильтрации при выводе (в вашем случае 5)

```
final int SEARCH_VALUE = 5;
System.out.println("Коррдинаты точек содержащие " + SEARCH_VALUE);
for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
     for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
         if (array[row][column] == SEARCH_VALUE) {
            System.out.print("(" + row + ";" + column + ")");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё то же самое можно сделать с помощью [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```java
int m = 3;
int n = 4;
// массив случайных чисел (n * m)
int[][] arr1 = IntStream.range(0, n)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, m)
                // генерируем случайное число
                .map(j -> (int) (Math.random() * 10))
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
int x = 5;
// поиск координат (x)
int[][] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, arr1[i].length)
                .filter(j -> arr1[i][j] == x)
                // (x) координаты
                .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j})
                .toArray(int[][]::new))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// вывод
Arrays.stream(arr1).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
[7, 8, 5]
[6, 8, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
[5, 1, 5]
```

```
[0, 2]
[3, 0]
[3, 2]
```